# Typescript Function Interface

Tags: interface, typescript

Why doesn't Typescript warn me that the function I am defining does not match the interface declaration, but it does warn me if I try to invoke the function.

```
interface IFormatter {
    (data: string, toUpper : boolean): string;
};

//Compiler does not flag error here.
var upperCaseFormatter: IFormatter = function (data: string) {
    return data.toUpperCase();
}  

upperCaseFormatter("test"); //but does flag an error here.
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The interface ensures that all callers of functions that implement the interface supply the required arguments - `data` and `toUpper`.

Because TypeScript understands that JavaScript doesn't mind if you pass arguments that aren't used, it cleverly allows this in implementations.

Why is this okay? Because it means you can substitute any implementation of the interface without affecting calling code.

Example: You can substitute either `IFormatter` implementation and the code works.

```
interface IFormatter {
    (data: string, toUpper: boolean): string;
};

var upperCaseFormatter: IFormatter = function (data: string) {
    return data.toUpperCase();
}

var variableCaseFormatter: IFormatter = function (data: string, toUpper: boolean) {
    if (toUpper) {
        return data.toUpperCase();
    }

    return data.toLowerCase();
}

// Switch between these at will
//var formatter = upperCaseFormatter;
var formatter = variableCaseFormatter;

formatter("test", true);
```

If TypeScript didn't do this, your `upperCaseFormatter` would have to have to have a parameter called `toUpper` that wasn't used anywhere in the function - which makes the code less readable.

Comment: But then using `upperCaseFormatter` has a redundant boolean value:  `upperCaseFormatter("test", true); // excluding the 'true' will result in a compiler warning`.  So instead the interface is wrong and should be:  `interface IFormatter { (data: string, toUpper? : bool): string; }`  But this then means that you can invoke `variableCaseFormatter` with just `variableCaseFormatter('test');`  without specifying `toUpper` despite it being in the function signature.  See my question here for a simpler example of my current confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305020

Comment: @AJP if you were writing clean code, you would never write a variable case formatter. You would write one class for upper and one for lower and avoid the nasty boolean argument altogether.

Comment: @AJP In the case that you call `upperCaseFormatter` directly the interface is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there a better syntax for providing such a function interface to an object method?
eg. { <IFormatter>myMethod() {return;}  }

Comment: This is totally wrong behavior of an interface IMO, Just look at other OOP languages