# Why does TypeScript not raise a warning when an interface is overridden

Tags: typescript

```
interface ClockInterface {
    setTime(d: Date);
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface  {
    // I would expect this to raise a compile error 
    // as it's not implementing the interface
    setTime(d) {
        // some logic that needs an instance of Date
    }
}

var cc = new Clock();

// otherwise it allows you to do any bad stuff you want.
cc.setTime(234);
cc.setTime('234');
cc.setTime([]);
```

Of course changing the `setTime(d) {` to `setTime(d: Date) {`  then does cause warnings to be raised for the last 3 invocations of `setTime`.

A simpler examples is just:

```
class Clock implements ClockInterface  {
    setTime() {
        // some logic that needs an instance of Date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The class is *substitutable* for the interface, so it does `implement` it.

The only check TypeScript performs when you say `implements` is "is the class assignable to the specified interface?". Consider this case:

```
interface CatVeterinarian {
    checkup(a: Cat): void;
}

interface HumanDoctor {
    checkup(a: Human): void;
}

class UniversalDoctor implements CatVeterinarian, HumanDoctor {
    checkup(a: Animal) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Presuppose for a minute that this *was* an error: How would you fix it? Your `UniversalDoctor` class really can act as both `CatVeterinarian` and `HumanDoctor`. There's nothing left for you to do.

The fact that you can invoke `Clock` with non-`Date` arguments simply represents an *extra* piece of functionality -- the ability to accept arbitrary `setTime` arguments. Obviously it would be absurd for the compiler to say "Your class does *too much*, it does not satisfy that interface*; nearly every implementor of an interface will have some extra 'stuff' that's not part of the original interface.

Comment: Ok, then I've misunderstood the purposes of interfaces.  What is their purpose if you declare a class as implementing them, and them promptly ignore the interface entirely?  (by the way, I think your example shouldn't error as long as `Human` and `Cat` extend `Animal`, but if you had implemented `UniversalDoctor` checkup as: `checkup(a: Rock) {...`, `checkup() {...` or `checkup(a: any) {...` or `CatVeterinarian` checkup was `checkup(a: Cat, owner: Human): void;` I would expect the UniversalDoctor checkup to error (otherwise what is the point in declaring a class implements the interface(s)?)

Comment: It would be an error in the cases you listed as expecting to be errors.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't error for me.  Try compiling this:  https://gist.github.com/AJamesPhillips/11308972  or running it here:  http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: And I guess my question is why can you have fewer arguments for the UniversalDoctor checkup method but not the other way around.  What purpose does that serve?

Comment: (1 / 2) TypeScript is a structural type system; all empty interfaces are interchangeable. Don't use empty interfaces for trying things out as many things won't error when they should.

Comment: (2 / 2) UniversalDoctor.checkup having 0 parameters means it will implement any function with the same return type. The general rule here is "you are allowed to ignore parameters for purposes of subtyping" (this is needed for things like Array#forEach, where the callback you pass doesn't *have* to declare every parameter it might not want)

Comment: "Don't use empty interfaces for trying things"  very good shout, have edited that gist and the second example now (correctly) errors.  And I understand interfaces more, I was just expecting they'd do more.  Thanks for being so responsive and helpful!